# HTML5 Audio - Sound only plays once

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, html5-audio

I am using Chrome and this is my code:

```
<audio id="letter_audio" src="audio/bomb.mp3" type="audio/mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

    $('.sound').live('click', function () {

        var sound = $("#letter_audio")[0];  

        sound.pause();
        sound.currentTime = 0;
        sound.play();

        return false;
    });
```

How come the sound plays the first time I click on play. then when I click again, it pauses, like the code goes. but the it justs stays on pause? i want it to play, then when i click on it again, go back to 0 and play again as in the code?

Comment: Tom's solution to add sound.load() worked for me

Answer (score 31):

I've had similar problems replaying audio, but managed to solve it by calling the `load()` method before the `play()` call.  Try this:

```
$('.sound').live('click', function () {
    var sound = $("#letter_audio")[0];

    sound.load();
    sound.play();

    return false;
});
```

I think this is better than resetting the `src` attribute for two reasons:

1. Keeps the `src` value in the page content, rather than in the JavaScript
2. Works when you embed multiple `<source>` elements of different audio formats:

   ```
   <audio id="letter_audio">
      <source src="audio/bomb.mp3" type="audio/mp3" preload="auto"/>
      <source src="audio/bomb.ogg" type="audio/ogg" preload="auto"/>
   </audio>
   ```

Comment: This is a good solution, but I wish I understood the cause of the problem better. `.load()` seems like overkill based on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Methods) and [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#loading-the-media-resource) descriptions. If I output `sound.error` after trying to `play()` the message is "failed to send audio packet for decoding". That sounds like a bug to me, but all I could find is something very loosely related. `.load()` isn't necessary for OGG files.

Answer (score 3):

try this.. basically, resetting the `src` attribute should reset the audio as desired.

```
$('.sound').live('click', function () {

    var sound = $("#letter_audio")[0];  

    sound.src = "audio/bomb.mp3";
    sound.play();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this works, but... it looks like its sending a request for the mp3 every time you "change" src. So thats a little expensive

Comment: It's not expensive - it's cheap.. only the first click instigates any network activity.. subsequent clicks access the mp3 directly in local disk cache - there is no cost at all.. see for yourself in Chrome Dev Tools, Network tab

Comment: yes, but he's right. everytime you *change* the src it will send a request.

Comment: This however doesn't work great if you have a file you're trying to play at intervals on mobile devices as all play actions need to be directed from a user interaction.  If you have your sound as a set variable then on the first initiation the file is "loaded" and you're able to use play again and again without having the user click buttons.

Comment: This also won't work when you are using multiple audio formats like `ogg`, `wav`, `mp3` inside the `source` tag..

Answer (score 0):

it seems that for the time being the currentTime attribute is read-only (and in 2011 it has got a [wont-fix status](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-bugs/alUTRVHJ3dI))

however, after setting `src` on your audio-object (again) - like also proposed by @Lloyd -  the currentTime attribute becomes settable (at least on a the current chrome-version for linux (24.0.1312.69)).

this means by adding the strange line

```
audio.src = audio.src
```

your example does what it is supposed to.

in full:

```
$('.sound').live('click', function () {

    var sound = $("#letter_audio")[0];  
    sound.src = sound.src;  
    sound.pause();
    sound.currentTime = 0;
    sound.play();

    return false;
});
```

as it is enough set the `src` once, you might want to call it somewhere during the setup process.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php to add a query at the end of the url with time();

`<source src="URLtoTrack.mp3?<?php echo time(); ?>" />`

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me September 2021 - tested in Chrome.

```
function playAudio(src) {

    // Get the audio element.
    var sound = $("#sound")[0];

    // Apply the new audio source.
    sound.src = src;

    // Load the sound.
    sound.load();

    // Set volume to default.
    sound.volume = 1;

    // Play the sound.
    sound.play();

    return false;
}
```

The volume to 1 is optional, but useful if you had faded out any previous audio (which I was) and you wonder why nothing plays!

You need to have an audio element on your page:

```
<audio id="sound">
    <source id="sound-src" src="" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

JS Usage :

```
playAudio('media/shake.mp3');
```

Working currently in Chrome Version 93.0.4577.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)