# HTML5 Audio Button - Works first time pressed, then stops working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have a button that when pressed it should play a short sound. It works the first time it is pressed and plays the sound. The next time and all other times it does not work (until I reload the page, then it works once again). My code is below:

I tried adding audio.stop(); before audio.play(); hoping it would fix it but it made it not work at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>HTML5</title>
</head>
<body>

<audio>
<source src="buzzer.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<input type="submit" id="buttonPlaySound" value="Play Sound">

<script>
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];

buttonPlaySound.onclick = function () { 
    audio.play();
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: Safari 6.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.8.2

Comment: Did you try this first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335577/html5-audio-sound-only-plays-once

Comment: @GertCuykens Checked it out, similar issue... adding audio.load(); before audio.play(); fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a different solution, and less prone to efficiency issues due to some agents reloading the file from remote is by calling `audio.currentTime = 0` before calling `audio.play()`
in your example this becomes:

```
buttonPlaySound.onclick = function () { 
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
};
```

**Edit**:
on chrome `currentTime` initially seems to be read-only. so this will not work. There is a workaround:
if you set `src` on the audio object manually (even to the same value as in: `audio.src = audio.src`) `currentTime` becomes settable and the above solution will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

This is because HTML5 audio played once and its state is playing so it won't play again.

You may try this:

```
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
var played = false;

buttonPlaySound.onclick = function () { 
    if (played) {
        audio.pause();
    }
    audio.play();
    played = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try like this..

```
<input type="submit" id="buttonPlaySound" value="Play Sound" onclick ="Play()">
<input type="submit" id="buttonPlaySound" value="Play Sound" onclick ="Pause()">

<script>
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
var played = false;

    function play() 
    {
        audio.play();
    }
    function pause()
    {
       if(played)
       {
           audio.pause();
       }
       audio.play();
       played = true;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding audio.load(); before audio.play(); fixed it for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>HTML5</title>
</head>
<body>

<audio>
<source src="buzzer.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<input type="submit" id="buttonPlaySound" value="Play Sound">

<script>
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];

buttonPlaySound.onclick = function () { 
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```