# audio.play() html tag doesn't play in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, html5-audio

I am facing an issue while playing audio in chrome when audio.src is not called preceeding to play call. However, firefox plays it alright. Can someone pls suggest? Below is the fiddle link -

http://jsfiddle.net/vn215r2d/1/

One can also find the code over here -

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script language="javascript">      
          var audioo = document.createElement("audio");

          function newCall() {        
              audioo.src = "";
              audioo.src = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8181/api/captcha/sound";
              audioo.play();               
          } 

          function playAgain() {               
               audioo.play(); // doesn't work in chrome :(
          } 

      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <button type="button" onClick="newCall()">New Captcha Call</button>
   <br>
   <button type="button" onClick="playAgain()">Replay Captcha</button>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried resetting the audio position? `audioo.currentTime = 0;` and then `audioo.play()` ?

Comment: try using load event on audio element.

Comment: does work for me on OsX Chrome v38.0

Comment: @somethinghere - .curentTime doesn't work. I've tried that?

Comment: @user3137592 Please check my answer below. I have tested it and it works, although the audio has to be loaded in first. I will amend my answer to help you discover that.

Comment: @theinvisible - the src attribute is being populated with a webservice url. So when I call a audio.load(), it basically makes a fresh audio call which isn't what's required here. I want audioo.play() to just play what was received in last call and not make a fresh call. This works fine on firefox.

Comment: @user3137592 Check updated answer below. I tested and it works. Use `newCall()` only to change your src. It will play as soon as its ready, and it will check whether audio is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Just replied on your comment, pls check.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

Oh waw, apparently is comes down to the audio.currentTime not being writeable until you rewrite the src. Heres what you can do and it does work:

```
function newCall() {  
    audioo.src = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8181/api/captcha/sound";
    // make all audio attributes writeable again by resetting the src
    audioo.src = audio.src;             
}
```

The answer took a bit of googling, but I got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14850353

#### Original

I tested on Chrome with resetting the audio position and it worked. Its safest to pause first, but it works either way.

```
var audioo = document.createElement("audio");

// Lets add an event listener to play when we are ready to start playing
audioo.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(){
    audioo.play(); 
}, false); 

function newCall() {        
     audioo.src = "";
     audioo.src = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8181/api/captcha/sound";             
} 

function playAgain() { 
     // Let's check if we are ready enough to play
     if(audioo.readyState === 4){                       
         audioo.pause(); // first pause        
         audioo.currentTime = 0; // then reset           
         audioo.play(); // then play
     } else {
         // else inform us that we are not ready to play yet.
         alert("Audio not ready yet.");
     }
}
```

Here are two fun resources that can help:

- [MDN:
     MediaElement (usefull properties and functions)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)
- [MDN:
     Media Events (for event listeners)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)

Comment: Ok I see what you are trying to say but currentTime=0 doesn't work for me. It might be because I am trying to call a webservice (GET call) through src attribute. When I call a local mp3 on my machine, it works fine even on chrome. Can you try a file that comes over network?

Comment: I have been able to actually get an audio file to play from over the network.. Are there any errors in your console? Like this one (if I enter an incorrect URL): `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ` ?

Comment: Nope, if that were the case. I'd have not heard the audio when I click on New Call button. The issue is that audio.play() is executed only one. If I remove audioo.play() from inside newcall() function, it executes in playAgain() function exactly once.

Comment: Check update but man, thats one strange problem! The solution works, though.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed strange, i've tried everything. Your update above throws a JS error because audio.src is undefined. Just in case you are interested to know, the audio.play() works well if I fetch audio data (wav) into audio.src instead of the url which fetches the data. However, as we saw earlier, using url plays it only once on chrome :(

Comment: You shouldnt get undefined though. Just to be sure, you didnt accidentally mistype the name since in the examples here its audioo with two o's, which my dictionairy kept correcting. I tried this and it worked in chrome....